# new ConcurrentHashMap of new ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, new-operator, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to initialize a `ConcurrentHashMap` of `ConcurrentHashMap`s with

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<
    String, 
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>
> myMulitiConcurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<
    String, 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>()
>();
```

but `javac` gives

```
HashMapper.java:132: error: illegal start of type
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>()
    ^
HashMapper.java:132: error: '(' or '[' expected
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>()
        ^
HashMapper.java:132: error: ';' expected
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>()
```

pointing to the second `new`.

How can `myMulitiConcurrentHashMap` be `new`ly initialized properly?

Comment: `new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NEEDS_A_TYPE_NOT_AN_EXPRESSION_HERE>()` (and `new ..` is an expression)

Comment: Note that it is very difficult to use such a map thread-safely.

Comment: @SLaks Thank-you!  Would you mind pointing to a link that outlines the thread-safety problems?  Thank-you so much in advance!

Comment: Remove the second "new".  It doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Gracchus: Because you can't make operations atomic.  What if one thread modifies an inner list as a different thread replaces it?  See also http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Comment: @SLaks Thank-you, and great blog entry!  In my case particular case at this moment, strict atomicity isn't required, but I'm sure I and others will benefit in the future from your very insightful blog entry!  I will surely keep it in my back pocket for when I need strict atomicity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, Java 7 has a more concise syntax now (the "diamond"):

```
private final 
   ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>>
      myMulitiConcurrentHashMap =
         new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

You should be able to use interfaces on the left hand side, too:

```
private final 
   ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Double>>
      myMulitiConcurrentHashMap =
         new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not initialize the inner `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>`; just the following should work:

```
new ConcurrentHashMap<
    String, 
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>
>();
```

Comment: Now both of you have used this indentation pattern. I've never seen it before, but there is some logic to it.

Comment: @Thilo I personally do not use this indentation pattern, but I chose to keep it consistent with the OP's original code.

Comment: @Thilo Right out of the jQuery handbook!  ;))

Answer (score 3):

Generic type parameters are exactly that – *types*.
It doesn't make sense to have a `Map<String, new SomeType()>`.
You need to simply write the *type* of the second parameter.

To paraphrase, you're creating a single `new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>()`, which can hold multiple inner maps later.