# loop through ConcurrentHashMap of ConcurrentHashMaps

Tags: java, loops, nested, concurrenthashmap

I have constructed a series of nested `ConcurrentHashMap`s initially with

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> allInOne = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>()
```

and subsequently with

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> accountMap = 
    (ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>)allInOne.get(account);
accountMap.put("subAccounts", new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>());
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> subAccountMap = 
    (ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>)accountMap.get(subAccount);
subAccountMap.put("subAccountData", new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>());
```

I want to loop through `subAccountMap`, so I can grab specific values from `subAccountData`.

I've tried all of the returned `Enumeration`s and `Set`s from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), but I can't make it work because I'm still too new to Java to figure it out.  Please show me how.

(I know what I'm doing is bad practice as many great stackers have shown me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318655/new-concurrenthashmap-of-new-concurrenthashmap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318655/new-concurrenthashmap-of-new-concurrenthashmap), but all I'm trying to do is quickly get a working prototype and will clean up the code once finished)

Comment: Please show what you've already tried and what went wrong. It's hard to know how to help you without that information.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you!  It's a real mess right now, so I'll try to clean up what I have and post asap.  The one I think I had the most luck with was based off of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3768659/1382306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
ConcurrentMap subAccounts = allInOne.get(account).get("subaccounts");
for (String key : subAccounts.keySet()) {
    Object subAccountObject = subAccounts.get(key);
}
```

Comment: The `for` line is perfect!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not use the entry set? Then you don't need to look up the entry on each iteration.